# How to generate a series containing each date for the following month relative to a given date in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, time-series, timestamp

My start point is the variable `data_published_date`

```
data_published_date
Out[47]: "DatetimeIndex(['2022-03-18'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)"
```

as it's a date in March, I wish to generate EACH day for the NEXT month as timestamp, like

```
['2022-04-01', '2022-04-02', '2022-04-03'.....'2022-04-30']
```

I tried

```
index = pd.date_range(data_published_date + pd.offsets.MonthBegin(n=1), data_published_date + pd.offsets.MonthEnd(n=1))
```

and received

> TypeError: Cannot convert input [DatetimeIndex(['2022-04-01'],
> dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)] of type <class
> 'pandas.core.indexes.datetimes.DatetimeIndex'> to Timestamp

tried then 2 steps

```
start_date = data_published_date + pd.offsets.MonthBegin(n=1)
end_date = data_published_date + pd.offsets.MonthEnd(n=2)
```

but can't find a solution to convert these 2 Datetimeindex to timestamp so that I can use `pd.date_range` to reach my objective.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is `data_published_date` is Index object, but `date_range` is expecting a singleton. Since it contains only a single element, we could index it and use that instead:

```
out = pd.date_range(data_published_date[0] + pd.offsets.MonthBegin(n=1), 
                    data_published_date[0] + pd.offsets.MonthEnd(n=2))
```

Output:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2022-04-01', '2022-04-02', '2022-04-03', '2022-04-04',
               '2022-04-05', '2022-04-06', '2022-04-07', '2022-04-08',
               '2022-04-09', '2022-04-10', '2022-04-11', '2022-04-12',
               '2022-04-13', '2022-04-14', '2022-04-15', '2022-04-16',
               '2022-04-17', '2022-04-18', '2022-04-19', '2022-04-20',
               '2022-04-21', '2022-04-22', '2022-04-23', '2022-04-24',
               '2022-04-25', '2022-04-26', '2022-04-27', '2022-04-28',
               '2022-04-29', '2022-04-30'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='D')
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working solution

```py
pd.date_range(start=(data_published_date + pd.offsets.MonthBegin(n=1)).date[0], 
end=(data_published_date + pd.offsets.MonthBegin(n=2)).date[0]-pd.Timedelta(days=1))
```

### Output:

```sh
DatetimeIndex(['2022-04-01', '2022-04-02', '2022-04-03', '2022-04-04',
               '2022-04-05', '2022-04-06', '2022-04-07', '2022-04-08',
               '2022-04-09', '2022-04-10', '2022-04-11', '2022-04-12',
               '2022-04-13', '2022-04-14', '2022-04-15', '2022-04-16',
               '2022-04-17', '2022-04-18', '2022-04-19', '2022-04-20',
               '2022-04-21', '2022-04-22', '2022-04-23', '2022-04-24',
               '2022-04-25', '2022-04-26', '2022-04-27', '2022-04-28',
               '2022-04-29', '2022-04-30'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='D')
```

I got the start of the next two months and subtracted 1 in the later month to have a range of one month alone.